# JQuery Get the name value from each input on the form

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic form generated by the user.  The input name is dynamic based upon the users previous inputs.  Therefore the input name could be anything. What I am trying to do is use JQuery to get the input name and  value of the input and place them in an array.
My array comes up empty.

I'm not that strong with JQuery and still learning it so your help is greatly appreciated

```
<input type="text" class="value" name="name1" value="0">
<input type="text" class="value" name="nameA" value="2">
<input type="text" class="value" name="name44" value="8">
<input type="text" class="value" name="janedoe" value="42">
```

jQuery

```
var myArray = [];
$('input').each(function() {
    var key = $('.value').attr('name');
    myArray.push(key);
});
console.log(myArray);
```

output on console

```
0: ""
1: ""
2: ""
3: ""
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

My array comes up empty.
The size of the array is correct, just empty for each value.

Comment: `this.name` for the property.  `$('.value').attr('name');` is saying to find all elements with a class of 'value', and get the first name attribute

Comment: I tried changing the values as you suggest and it worked.  I did find that I had an error in my php class that was not transferring the error to JQuery so it was not dynamically entering the input name.   When I fixed my error in the php class, my method still did not work.  Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `serializeArray()` method.

```js
console.log(
  $(':input').serializeArray()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="value" name="name1" value="0">
<input type="text" class="value" name="nameA" value="2">
<input type="text" class="value" name="name44" value="8">
<input type="text" class="value" name="janedoe" value="42">
```

Otherwise...

```js
console.log(
  //get the array of inputs and reduce them to a single object
  $(':input[name]').get().reduce(function(result, input){
    result[input.name] = input.value;
    
    return result;
  }, {})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="value" name="name1" value="0">
<input type="text" class="value" name="nameA" value="2">
<input type="text" class="value" name="name44" value="8">
<input type="text" class="value" name="janedoe" value="42">
```

Comment: Thank you,  as I said I am still learning JQuery, and I tried your serialize and it just opened up a whole new avenue to explore.  I am sure I will have additional questions but thanks.

Comment: @Mike np, hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest the following:

```
var myArray = [];
$('input').each(function() {
  myArray.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
console.log(myArray);
```

If you want, can do this:

```
var myData = {};
$('input').each(function() {
  myData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
console.log(myData);
```

Hope that helps.